# Net view command in windows not showing all the computers connected to the network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, monitoring

I have updated my OS from windows 7 to 10 recently and I am trying to find out all the devices connected to my wifi network. But on using **NET View** in the command prompt, it shows only my device but whereas I myself had 4 devices connected to the network i.e, my laptop, mobile, tab and another laptop just to check if it works.

So now what are the other ways to see who all are connected to my network?

Comment: Depending what router you have, you may be able to see DHCP or actively connected clients in the web gui

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your end goal is, but if you're trying to find out if there are unauthorized users/devices on your wireless network `net view` is probably not the way to go as I'm pretty sure it relies on NetBIOS to get all of its information.  So, it will mostly show other Windows devices on your network, but not likely any Unix devices (not sure about iOS/Apple devices).  And even that is going to be restricted by firewall settings both on your device and the remote devices.

As [@adampski](https://superuser.com/users/274145/adampski) suggested in his comment, you're much better off using the management interface/web site on your wireless router/access point to determine what is connected to your network.